# Mapping to different class filehelpers slow

Tags: c#, entity, filehelpers

I mapping some records to a csv file using filehelpers libary but its rather slow so it is as I have to map it to another class.

```
private List<ItemsExport>  MapItems(List<Items> tradeItem)
    {

var retList = new List<ItemsExport>();

        try
        {

            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                retList.Add(new ItemsExport()
                {
                    ItemCode = item.ItemCode,
                    BarCode = item.BarCode,
                    Description = item.Description,
                    SupplierCode = item.SupplierCode,
                    SupplierStockCode = item.SupplierStockCode,
                    Product_Group_Code = "",
                    Product_Group_Desc = "",
                    SportCode = GetProductAnaylisCodeValue(item.ItemCode, Constants.Sport).ToString(),
                    SportDesc = GetProductAnaylisCodeDesc(item.ItemCode, Constants.Sport).ToString(),
                    GenderCode = GetProductAnaylisCodeValue(item.ItemCode, Constants.Gender).ToString(),
                    GenderDesc = GetProductAnaylisCodeDesc(item.ItemCode, Constants.Gender).ToString(),
                    ColourCode = GetProductAnaylisCodeValue(item.ItemCode, Constants.Colour).ToString(),
                    ColourDesc = GetProductAnaylisCodeDesc(item.ItemCode, Constants.Colour).ToString(),
                    SizeCode = GetProductAnaylisCodeValue(item.ItemCode, Constants.Size).ToString(),
                    SizeDesc = GetProductAnaylisCodeDesc(item.ItemCode, Constants.Size).ToString(),
                    CategoryCode = GetProductAnaylisCodeValue(item.ItemCode, Constants.Category).ToString(),
                    CategoryDesc = GetProductAnaylisCodeDesc(item.ItemCode, Constants.Category).ToString(),
                    SearchCategoryCode = GetProductAnaylisCodeValue(item.ItemCode, Constants.SubCategory).ToString(),
                    SeearchCategoryDesc = GetProductAnaylisCodeDesc(item.ItemCode, Constants.SubCategory).ToString(),
                    Vat = item.Vat,
                    GrossWeight = item.Weight,
                    CommodityCode = item.CommodityCode,
                    price_exVAT = item.price_exVAT,
                    price_incVAT = item.price_incVAT,
                    currentprice_exVAT = item.currentprice_exVAT,
                    currentprice_incVAT = item.currentprice_incVAT,
                    creation_date = item.creation_date,
                    Inactive_date = item.Inactive_date,
                    status = 1



                });
            }
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }

        return retList;
```

}

The following is how I am calling the above.

```
 using (var db = new  xxxEntities1())
 {
                List<Items> items = db.Items.AsNoTracking().ToList();

                var mapped = MapTradeItems(items);
 }
```

Is there a better way to dump to csv that doesnt take as long?. Its only reporting item count of.

> Count = 116378

And this takes a few mins to complete?. The initial line here only takes a few seconds to complete cause of the no tracking is their something similar I can do to speed up above ?.

> List items = db.Items.AsNoTracking().ToList();

My GetProductAnaylisCodeValueValue is below for code completeness.

```
public string  GetProductAnaylisCodeValue(string ItemCode, string CategoryName)
{
   string retResult = "";
   try
       {

        using (var db = new xxxEntities1())
                {
        var paramItemCode = new SqlParameter("@ItemCode", ItemCode);
        var paramCategoryName = new SqlParameter("@CategoryName", CategoryName);

        StockItemSearchCategoryDescriptions_Result result = db.Database.SqlQuery<StockItemSearchCategoryDescriptions_Result>("StockItemSearchCategoryDescriptions @ItemCode ,@CategoryName", paramItemCode, paramCategoryName).FirstOrDefault();
        retResult = result.ProductGroupValue;
                }
            }catch(Exception EX)
            {

            }
       return retResult;
 }
```

Ok from below advice i changed my call to a in memory list but the for each is still super slow.

```
  private List<ItemsExport> MapTradeItems(List<TradeItems> tradeItem)
    {
        var retList = new List<TradeItems>();

      try
        {

                List<StandardLookUpList > _AnalsisCodes = GetAnayalsisCodesForExportCode();


            foreach (var item in tradeItem)
            {
                retList.Add(new FuelImportSage.Classes.Export.TradeItemsExport()
                {
                    ItemCode = item.ItemCode,
                    BarCode = item.BarCode,
                    Description = item.Description,
                    SupplierCode = item.SupplierCode,
                    SupplierStockCode = item.SupplierStockCode,
                    Product_Group_Code = "",
                    Product_Group_Desc = "",
                    SportCode = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.Sport).FirstOrDefault().code.ToString(),
                    SportDesc = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.Sport).FirstOrDefault().description.ToString(),
                    GenderCode = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.Gender).FirstOrDefault().code.ToString(),
                    GenderDesc = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.Gender).FirstOrDefault().description.ToString(),
                    ColourCode = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.Colour).FirstOrDefault().code.ToString(),
                    ColourDesc = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.Colour).FirstOrDefault().description.ToString(),
                    SizeCode = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.Size).FirstOrDefault().code.ToString(),
                    SizeDesc = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.Size).FirstOrDefault().description.ToString(),
                    CategoryCode = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.Category).FirstOrDefault().code.ToString(),
                    CategoryDesc = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.Category).FirstOrDefault().description.ToString(),
                    SearchCategoryCode = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.SubCategory).FirstOrDefault().code.ToString(),
                    SeearchCategoryDesc = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode && w.code == Constants.SubCategory).FirstOrDefault().description.ToString(),
                    Vat = item.Vat,
                    GrossWeight = item.Weight,
                    CommodityCode = item.CommodityCode,
                    price_exVAT = item.price_exVAT,
                    price_incVAT = item.price_incVAT,
                    currentprice_exVAT = item.currentprice_exVAT,
                    currentprice_incVAT = item.currentprice_incVAT,
                    creation_date = item.creation_date,
                    Inactive_date = item.Inactive_date,
                    status = 1



                });
            }
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }

        return retList;

    }
```

Comment: For a start you're creating an intermediate list that is not required, you could use `.Select(...)` to project directly to a list of `ItemsExport`. However, that depends on what `GetProductAnaylisCodeValue` etc. does. Finally, 116k items is still a lot of data...

Comment: My guess is that it's not the mapping that's slow, but the file write

Comment: @DavidG I included that in my above edit for completeness but the tolist is supper fast lit it in two to three seconds is there any way to speed up a write maybe not using filehelpers?.

Comment: So that function calls a stored procedure. That means you're calling 12 stored procs for every row, that's nearly 1.4 million procedure calls, and you're wondering why it's slow?!

Comment: I suppose that makes since I should make a master call that places those in memory instead thanks.

Comment: @DavidG i changed the above to one list but its still super slow.